# AndriodStudio 4.1 ошибка: AAPT2 process unexpectedly exit. Error output

Tags: android-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Обновился до AndriodStudio 4.1, стала вылазить ошибка и не запускается программа на реальном устройстве.
Удалил и установил AndriodStudio 4.0 - работает нормально
Удалил и установил AndriodStudio 4.1 - опять ошибка

Может какой патч очередной надо скачать на Windows7?
Что надо сделать чтобы случилось чудо и программа на AndroidStudio 4.1 запустилась?

[image: stackoverflow.ru]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]